# Conjecture about the totient function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Inspired by a conjecture of user Ante , I arrived at the following strengthened conjecture :

> Let $\ m\ $ be a positive integer with $\ m\neq 3\mod 6\ $. Then, there exists a positive integer $\ n\ $ with $\ \gcd(m,n)=1\ $ and $\ \varphi(n)=\varphi(n+m)\ $

$\varphi(n)$ is the totient function.

For numbers of the form $\ 6k+3\ $ , I did not always find a solution, for example I found none for $\ m=9\ $.

The conjecture is true at least upto $\ m=\ 30\ 000\ $

Can we proof or disproof it ?

Comment: This is tangentially related to Carmichael's conjecture, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael%27s_totient_function_conjecture to the effect that for every $n$ there exists $m\ne n$ such that $\phi(m)=\phi(n)$.

Comment: A bit related, but here I search for a specific duplicate. I do not see how this conjecture helps us here.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't. Maybe some of the methods people have used to investigate Carmichael can be put to use. Anyway, it's always nice to know about famous open problems, don't you think?

Comment: I agree that mentioning such a conjecture is not a bad idea. It is interesting in particular because of the lower bound of a possible counterexample !