# Even more surprising conjecture

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, totient-function

Closely related to this :

[Conjecture about the totient function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3601543/conjecture-about-the-totient-function)

$\varphi(n)$ is again the totienr function.

> If $\ m\ $ is a positive integer coprime to $\ 15\ $ , there exists a positive integer $\ p\ $ such that $\ \varphi(pm+1)=\varphi(pm+m+1)\ $ , hence we can choose the desired number $\ n\ $ even to be congruent to $\ 1\ $ mod $\ m\ $.

Since some solutions are very large, I consider to also check the cases that $\ m\ $ is not coprime to $\ 15\ $ , for which I sometimes did not find a solution, but maybe just because I gave up too early.

The conjecture is true upto at least $\ m=427\ $

Comment: What is $n$ and why would we want to choose it?

Comment: @Hagen I think $n$ refers to the problem in the link.

Comment: Is this the same as https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356105/how-to-explain-this-property-of-totient Peter?

Comment: Apparently the answer to my question is "no" – though I think it's good to link the two questions anyway.

Comment: @GerryMyerson It is very closely related to the linked question, $n$ is here just more special.